# applescript to copy folders into Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, applescript

I'm having some trouble copying folders into XCode projects with AppleScript.  Without Applescript I drag the folder into Xcode.

I've used a similar Applescript handler, as the one shown below, to copy libraries into XCode using "wrapper.library" for the file type.  Below I am using "wrapper.folder" to try to copy a folder into XCode and it isn't working.

```
    on addFolder(fname, fpath)
  tell application "Xcode"
   tell project "Unity-iPhone"
    set my_targets to targets
    set s_target to item 1 of my_targets
    set compile_phase to compile sources phase of s_target
    set link_phase to get link binary with libraries phase of s_target
    tell root group
     set a to make new file reference with properties {full path:fpath & fname, name:fname, file type:"wrapper.folder"}
     add a to link_phase
    end tell
   end tell
  end tell
    end addFolder
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what I am missing or how to write an Applescript to copy a folder into XCode?

Comment: This Xcode plugin might help: https://github.com/larsxschneider/Xcode-Scripting-Interface

Comment: I am curious to know how did you solve this problem...

Comment: I've never found a solution except to move the folders manually.  I know it can be done, because I have used compiled Applescripts that can move folders.

Comment: Based on the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022009/adding-files-via-applescript-to-an-xcode-project-target It might be possible that the Xcode AppleScript add command is broken.

Comment: If the add command is broken, would a compiled AppleScript still be able to add a folder to an Xcode project?

Comment: @JamesTesta No, the command needs to be interpreted by Xcode in order to function.

Answer (score 1):

It is working for me:

```
--this is for xcode 3.x
tell application "Xcode"
    tell active project document
        tell root group
            --Note: Large folders make it seems that the script is hanging. Give it some time to list all items in the given folder.
            make new file reference with properties {name:"My Desktop Folder", full path:(POSIX path of (path to desktop folder)), file type:"wrapper.folder"}
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

The code for Xcode 4 is a bit different

```
--this is for Xcode 4.x
tell application "Xcode"
    tell project 1
        tell root group
            --Note: big folders make it seems that the application (not the script like in Xcode 3) is hanging. Give it some time to list all items in the given folder.
            make new file reference with properties {name:"My Desktop Folder", full path:(POSIX path of (path to desktop folder)), file kind:"folder"}
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

The option 'copy to destination folder if needed' just copy the files to the project (if they're not already in there) and then make a file reference to the copied files instead of the original files. You can do the same with the Finder or a shell command like cp or ditto, then make a reference to the copied files. Then I wouldn't use full path but relative paths instead. With relative paths moving the project to another folder won't give you any problems.

Comment: Interesting. This adds a folder file reference to the project. (Notice the folder icon is blue, not yellow.) However, these files are not added to the build or copy phase of the project.