# How do I add files to targets in Xcode using rb-appscript?

Tags: xcode, rb-appscript

I am trying to automatically add files to my Xcode project using rb-appscript.  I don't have much experience with Ruby or Applescript, but two people seem to have made this work for them:

https://github.com/gonzoua/xcs/blob/master/xcs.thor

[Automatically adding generated source files to an xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965077/automatically-adding-generated-source-files-to-an-xcode-project)

Unfortunately neither of these work for me.  I can get them to add files to groups, but adding files to targets breaks.  Here is the simplest piece of code that doesn't work for me:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'appscript'

project_path = 'Users:me:Projects:xcode:project:src:AppScaffold.xcodeproj'
project_name = 'AppScaffold'
group_name = 'Classes'
file_name = 'ApplicationDelegate.m'
target_name = 'AppScaffold'

def lookup(sequence, name)
  sequence.get.each { |item|
    if item.name.get == name
      return item
    end
  }
  raise Exception.new("Couldn't find name '" + name + "' in sequence " + sequence.inspect)
end

app = Appscript.app('Xcode')
app.open(project_path)

project = lookup(app.projects, project_name)
target = lookup(project.targets, target_name)
group = lookup(project.root_group.item_references, group_name)
file = lookup(group.item_references, file_name)

file.add({:to => target})
# I also tried this:
# app.add(file, {:to => target})
```

This fails with this message:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1/lib/appscript.rb:542:in `_send_command': CommandError (Appscript::CommandError)
        OSERROR: -1708
        MESSAGE: Application could not handle this command.
        COMMAND: app("/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app").workspace_documents["project.xcworkspace"].projects["AppScaffold"].root_group.Xcode_3_groups.ID("080E96DDFE201D6D7F000001").Xcode_3_file_references.ID("1D3623250D0F684500981E51").add({:to=>app("/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app").workspace_documents["project.xcworkspace"].projects["AppScaffold"].targets.ID("1D6058900D05DD3D006BFB54")})
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1/lib/appscript.rb:642:in `method_missing'
    from add_to_target.rb:28
```

Note that I am using Xcode 4, but my project seems to have "Xcode_3_references".  This is also the case for projects I create from scratch; I'm not sure why.

Anyway, I'm not sure what to make of this error message, or where to find documentation on this.  (I looked at the Xcode dictionary, but it didn't have much to say about "add".)  Any advice would be great.  I'm not married to rb-appscript, I just want to add files to my project programmatically.

Comment: Can you explain the initial problem do you want to solve? Maybe there is an alternative solution.

Comment: Based on the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022009/adding-files-via-applescript-to-an-xcode-project-target It is possible that the xcode add command doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do and whether you are building for the Mac or for iOS. Therefore I'm not sure if I can be of much help. If you are simply trying to add files to your project for the sake of bundling them rather than compiling them in the build then you do not need to code this. Instead click on your project at the top of your files list on the left hand panel, then in the main window click on your target bundle. This should give you a screen with the options 'summary - info - build settings - build phases - build rules' along the top. Click on build phases and then choose copy bundle resources form the list below. Then click the + sign at the bottom of this list and select the file you want to copy to the bundle during the build.

That said, if the file has to be added programmatically then you would need a more advanced user than me to answer your question. Though, in thinking about it, I guess it depends on the type of file, where you are getting it from and the permissions required to do this on the iphone. If you are building for the OSX then I'm in unknown water and this advice probably isn't that helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I do want to do this programmatically.  However, based on the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686802/how-do-i-get-xcode-to-build-and-run-using-applescript), it looks like this might not be possible with Xcode 4.

Comment: Look into the Xcode file format - each project is a bundle containing XML manifests which you can manipulate by simply changing the xml with ruby to add files to targets etc.

Answer (score 1):

So, one issue with Xcode since it moved to the AppStore is that older versions were left intact, and not removed - not to mention the binaries are all different (llvm vs cc).  It wasn't the same issue you are having, but I did run into complications using the command-line compilers for things like homebrew, and came across this command:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html

I don't know for sure here, but it's possible this will "re-orient" the build system you are working with to reference the current xcode and not the older version, which may have the intended result.

Comment: @traversable, did you try the above... did it work/not work?  Just wondering if this was the answer.